# how to link specific version of shared library in g++

Tags: c++, c, openssl, shared-libraries

I have the following shared libraries:
`libssl.so, libssl.so.1.1, libcurl.so, libcurl.so.4, libcurl.so.4.4.0, libcrypto.so, libcrypto.so.1.1`.
All of the libraries are in the `openssl` folder.
My question is, how can I link version 1.1 of libssl? Is it done automatically?
I've tried the following:

```
g++ -c my_file_name.cpp -std=c++11 -w -fpermissive -lpthread --coverage $(INCLUDES) `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` -O0 -Lopenssl -lcrypto -lcurl -lssl
g++ my_file_name.o -o ex -std=c++11 -w -fpermissive -lpthread --coverage -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` -O0 -Lopenssl -lcrypto -lcurl -lssl
```

But it seems that the link doesn't happen. As I still get errors like:
 `error: ‘X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain’ was not declared in this scope`

**Later edit**
`nm libssl.so.1.1 | grep X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain` results in `0000000000218210 T X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain`. That would mean that the link that I've done does not happen.

It's worth mentioning that the error comes from a `.c` file included in the `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `libssl.so` is a symbolic link to `libssl.so.1.1` etc. etc.
The problem seems to be related to the missing implementation in one of these library of this function :`X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain`.
Now you have to check if this symbol is defined in one of these library you link, or if you need to link someone else.

To check this you can execute the following command over each library:

```
nm libToCheck.so | grep X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain
```

if no one have this symbol defined maybe you missing some library to link.
If exist, check the scope of the utilizzation of the function, it could not correspond to the scope declared in the library. Check the namespace or similar.

Comment: `nm libssl.so.1.1 | grep X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain`  results in `0000000000218210 T X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain`. That would mean that the link that I've done does not happen. Any more ideas?

Comment: Ok, so the scope of the utilizzation of the function does not correspond to the scope declared in the library. Check the namespace or similar

Comment: That's where the situation gets tricky. The error code comes from a `.c` file that I've included in the `.cpp` in order to perform some unit tests.